# newtonsoft.json parser in a C# CLR for SQL Server 2008 R2 - How to deploy?

Tags: c#, .net, json, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlclr

I have created a `CLR` which uses the `newtonsoft json parser.`

I need to deploy the `CLR`. I have created an assembly for the parser dependency:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json] FROM 'C:\share\Release\Newtonsoft.Json.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

The above statement throws an error:

```
`Assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' references assembly 'system.runtime.serialization, version=3.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: 2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)).` Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.
```

I am using version `7.xx` of the `parser`.
I am targeting `.NET 3.5`

What is the proper procedure for deploying the `CLR` to `sql server 2008 r2`?

Comment: Do you have .net 3.5 installed on the Sql machine? System.Runtime.Serialization should be in the GAC

Comment: How do I tell? According to:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx , if I check the NDP subkey, I have entries for all the .Net versions (2, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5 (under full)). In add and remove programs, .net 4.5.2 is present. It is my understanding that SQL Server 2008 R2 uses .Net 3.5. Is this correct? Note: If I try to target .NET 4.0 in my CLR build, deployment fails stating wrong .NET version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I had made an incorrect assumption in my comment. Only [certain libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx) in the GAC are supported for SQL CLR by default.

In order to use that library, you'll need to explicitly add it as well.

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY System_Runtime_Serialization FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO
```

If you are using 64-bit SQL Server, make sure you use Framework64 instead of Framework.

Comment: Yes, that's it. (I was trying to register an incorrect dll). Thank-you

Comment: This give `Assembly 'System_Runtime_Serialization' could not be installed because existing policy would keep it from being used.`. What should be done to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving a note in a bottle, since I just ran into this a part of a Sql Server upgrade/move to a different system.

Newer versions of Sql Server are much stricter about assemblies getting loaded into the database.

We had an assembly using Newtonsoft.json 7.0.1, and that assembly loaded fine once I signed it with a certificate.

Then I tried upgrading Newtonsoft to 11.0.2.  That turned up the dependency on System.Runtime.Serialization, as mentioned here.

The path for that assembly is different than the answer above:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
```

Then it turned out that System.Runtime.Serialization was dependent on System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.  When I attempted to load that assembly into Sql Server 2019, it failed with the error that the certificate used to sign that assembly had expired.

So if you keep to Newtonsoft.json 7.0.1, there are a lot fewer dependencies to resolve here.  Or depending on what features you need, maybe Utf8Json or some other project would have fewer dependencies that need to be loaded into Sql Server

EDIT:  Okay, this is probably 17 different shades of bad, but I found what I had before that was working was the ...\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1\lib\**net20** version of the file.  Someone had kinda short-circuited the nuget manager and locked it to that one.  **That** loaded into the Sql Server 2019 database Assemblies area without any reference to System.Runtime.Serialization (or System.ServiceModel.Internals) which was causing all kinds of problems.

Didn't matter if I changed the target in packages.config back to 2.0, it would try to grab the newer framework Newtonsoft dlls to match the other code.

Just for grins, I tried upgrading to Newtonsoft 11.0.2 and forcing the use of the net20 dll, and that loaded into Sql Server 2019 without the need to load the other .net framework dlls, too.

Not sure what functional differences there might be between all of the build targets from Newtonsoft, but loading the net20 ones seem to come with a lot fewer strings attached when it comes to getting them into Sql Server 2019