# CLR SQL User Defined Function

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I wanted to write my own JSON parser for SQL Server 2012. For this I would like to use the CLR integration feature, but I'm facing with a problem.

I would like to use the Newtonsoft JSON DLL but I noticed that it's not on the white list of the DLL's we can use in such a scenarios.

Can you suggest me some tips how can I integrate third party DLL's into the SQL Server project which finally can be deployed to the target database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the same question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/12479/44324

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794855/newtonsoft-json-parser-in-a-c-sharp-clr-for-sql-server-2008-r2-how-to-deploy